# Show another form adjacent to the one its spawned from C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How would it be possible to spawn a new form e.g. `Form2` from `Form1`, but make sure `Form2` is adjacent to `Form1`, for example:

[image]

Comment: Forms have a [`Location` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159414.aspx). Does that help?

Comment: @Cody Gray Yes it does thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try handling the `LocationChanged` event of the main form.

Simple demo:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
  Form2 f2;

  public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.LocationChanged += new EventHandler(Form1_LocationChanged);
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    f2 = new Form2();
    f2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    f2.Location = new Point(this.Right, this.Top);
    f2.Height = this.Height;
    f2.Show();
  }

  void Form1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (f2 != null)
      f2.Location = new Point(this.Right, this.Top);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like:

```
// button click handler method

Form2 child = new Form2();
child.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + this.Width, 
                           this.location.Y);
child.Show();
```

Take the X coordinate of the location of the current form object and add to it the width of the form, thus obtaining the X coordinate of the new form. The Y coordinate stays the same.

Comment: Thanks, but I assume the window would not "stay glued" on to the other window / form?

Comment: @Mike: You did not specify this requirement.

Answer (score 3):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 frm2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frm2 = new Form2(this);
        frm2.Show();
    }
}
```

And:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 frm1;
    public Form2(Form1 frm1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.frm1 = frm1;
        frm1.Move += new EventHandler(Form1_Move);
    }

    void Form1_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Location = new Point(frm1.Location.X + frm1.Width, frm1.Location.Y);
    }
}
```

EDIT: (Due to a comment)

To make `Form1` follow `Form2` as well, add:

```
Move += new EventHandler(Form2_Move);
```

To `Form2`'s constructor.

And:

```
void Form2_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frm1.Location = new Point(Location.X - frm1.Width, Location.Y);
}
```

In its class.

Comment: @Groo Thanks. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help you. Button1 is on form1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            form2.SetDesktopLocation(this.Location.X + this.Width, this.Location.Y);
            form2.ShowDialog();
        }
```