# Create a "stuck windows" application

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm creating a *stuck windows* application (like `TeamViewer 10`) which should look like this :

[image]

But I've two problems :

- First, if I use the following code to show `Form2` during loading of `Form1`, it shows `Form2` first and then the 1st form.

  ```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      Form2.Show()
  End Sub
  ```

So I've this, but it's not what I wanted...

[image]

...but I found a solution : I set my `Form2` as startup form and then I show `Form1` during the loading of `Form2`. **Is there a simpler way or more logical way to do it ?**

- **Secondly, how can I focus my `Form1` (main form) when the 2 forms are loaded ?** For now, I've this code (it works but it's a bit weird to do it this way...) :

  ```
  Private Sub MainFormFocus_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MainFormFocus.Tick
      Form1.Focus()
      MainFormFocus.Stop()
  End Sub
  ```

The `MainFormFocus` object is a `Timer` with the `Enabled` property set to `True`, and the `Interval` set to 1.

All the code above works, but is a bit tricky... It's why I'd like to do it in a different way.

Comment: You are focusing on the wrong problem.  You need to subscribe the LocationChanged property so you can position the other window correctly.  Now it just doesn't matter anymore which window is "first".

Comment: For me, it matters !

Comment: If you show Form2 inside the load event of Form1, then naturally it will be visible first since Form1 will not be visible until its load event has completed.  You might try showing Form2 inside Form1's OnFormShown override instead.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I'll try this, thanks !

Comment: See [Show another form adjacent to the one its spawned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8871949/719186)

Comment: @LarsTech My problem is resolved, moreover, your link doesn't answer my problem... Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ***Chris Dunaway***, there's a solution to my problems :

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnShown(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnShown(e)
    Me.Location = New Point((My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - (Me.Width + 5 + Form2.Width)) \ 2, Me.Location.Y)
    Form2.Show()
    Form2.Location = New Point(Me.Location.X + Me.Width + 5, Me.Location.Y)
    Me.Focus()
End Sub
```

The code above is in my `Form1` which is reset to startup form.