# How to dock a WinForms App to another running application

Tags: c#, winforms

Can someone help out with this one. I have had a good Google search but cannot find anything - possibility I'm using the wrong terminology.

Basically I want to write a WinForms app that on starting docks to a specified running app by default, but can also be moved and snapped in any location on that or other running apps (the latter is a nice to have, no biggie if too hard).

Cheers!

EXAMPLE OF 3RD PARTY APP SNAPPING TO SKYPE FOR BUSINESS:
[image]

Comment: Post an image what you are looking for. Seems like sticky windows http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6045/Sticky-Windows-How-to-make-your-top-level-forms-to or maybe teamviewer style http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592431/create-a-stuck-windows-application

Comment: You'll need a notification when that window is moved or hidden, not exactly easy to come by when the window is owned by another process.  You can get one by pinvoking SetWinEventHook().  Google knows about it.

Comment: Write a VSTO addin for Word or a Shared AddIn for Office apps if those are the apps you wish to dock too. Also please show your research and code.

Comment: Teamviewer is a perfect example, the only difference is that I want to stick to a 3rd party application. In my case I want to snap to an Office app - Skype for Business. Example of a company doing the same attached.

Comment: Try looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773003/attach-form-window-to-another-window-in-c-sharp

Comment: Cheers for the link - looks like what I am after. I will give it a test and let you know :)

Comment: Tested this and some other things from links found within the linked provided. I have posted a new question with the code from my attempt to make this work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806280/attach-wpf-window-to-the-window-of-another-process

Comment: @AndrewMorpeth did you found a solution? Does workaround help you to build skype embedded to winform?