# Attach WPF Window to the Window of Another Process

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to write a WPF application that docks to an application running in another process (this is a 3rd party app I have no control of). Ideally I would like to be able to define if the app docks on the left or right.

Here's an example of what I want to do:

[image: Docked example]

I have tried to implement the following 2 examples with no success.

[Attach window to window of another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676649/attach-window-to-window-of-another-process) - Button_Click gives the following error:

[image: error image]

[Attach form window to another window in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773003/attach-form-window-to-another-window-in-c-sharp) - Button_Click_1 docks it the title bar but I cannot see the entire app:

[image: App docked]

The following is the code:

```
namespace WpfApplicationTest
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    public static int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    public static int WS_CHILD = 0x40000000;

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPos(
        IntPtr hWnd,
        IntPtr hWndInsertAfter,
        int x,
        int y,
        int cx,
        int cy,
        uint uFlags);

    private IntPtr _handle;
    private void SetBounds(int left, int top, int width, int height)
    {
        if (_handle == IntPtr.Zero)
            _handle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;

        SetWindowPos(_handle, IntPtr.Zero, left, top, width, height, 0);
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Process hostProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();
        IntPtr hostHandle = hostProcess.MainWindowHandle;

        //MyWindow window = new MyWindow();
        this.ShowActivated = true;

        HwndSourceParameters parameters = new HwndSourceParameters();

        parameters.WindowStyle = 0x10000000 | 0x40000000;
        parameters.SetPosition(0, 0);
        parameters.SetSize((int)this.Width, (int)this.Height);
        parameters.ParentWindow = hostHandle;
        parameters.UsesPerPixelOpacity = true;
        HwndSource src = new HwndSource(parameters);

        src.CompositionTarget.BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
        src.RootVisual = (Visual)this.Content;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Process hostProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();
        if (hostProcess != null)
        {
            Hide();

            //this.WindowStyle;

            //new WindowInteropHelper(this).SetBounds(0, 0, 0, 0, BoundsSpecified.Location);

            //SetWindowPos(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            SetBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);

            IntPtr hostHandle = hostProcess.MainWindowHandle;
            IntPtr guestHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;

            SetWindowLong(guestHandle, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(guestHandle, GWL_STYLE) | WS_CHILD);
            SetParent(guestHandle, hostHandle);

            Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'dock' exactly?

Comment: Dock = attach to the side of

Comment: You might try googling using the phrase "snap to" rather than "dock to".

Comment: I spent a lot of time googling before I submitted this question with various key words including snap to.

Answer (score 4):

You implementation is totally wrong, you are trying to make your window as a child window of the window you want to snap to.

I wrote a small helper class for snapping to another window by it's title, I hope this helps.

**WindowSnapper.cs**

```c#
public class WindowSnapper
{
    private struct Rect
    {
        public int Left { get; set; }
        public int Top { get; set; }
        public int Right { get; set; }
        public int Bottom { get; set; }

        public int Height
        {
            get { return Bottom - Top; }
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Rect r1, Rect r2)
        {
            return !(r1 == r2);
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Rect r1, Rect r2)
        {
            return r1.Left == r2.Left && r1.Right == r2.Right && r1.Top == r2.Top && r1.Bottom == r2.Bottom;
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, ref Rect rectangle);

    private DispatcherTimer _timer;
    private IntPtr _windowHandle;
    private Rect _lastBounds;
    private Window _window;
    private string _windowTitle;

    public WindowSnapper(Window window, String windowTitle)
    {
        _window = window;
        _window.Topmost = true;
        _windowTitle = windowTitle;

        _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
        _timer.Tick += (x, y) => SnapToWindow();
        _timer.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    public void Attach()
    {
        _windowHandle = GetWindowHandle(_windowTitle);
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public void Detach()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
    }

    private void SnapToWindow()
    {
        var bounds = GetWindowBounds(_windowHandle);

        if (bounds != _lastBounds)
        {
            _window.Top = bounds.Top;
            _window.Left = bounds.Left - _window.Width;
            _window.Height = bounds.Height;
            _lastBounds = bounds;
        }
    }

    private Rect GetWindowBounds(IntPtr handle)
    {
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        GetWindowRect(handle, ref bounds);
        return bounds;
    }

    private IntPtr GetWindowHandle(string windowTitle)
    {
        foreach (Process pList in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (pList.MainWindowTitle.Contains(windowTitle))
            {
                return pList.MainWindowHandle;
            }
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
```

**Usage example:**

```c#
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private WindowSnapper _snapper;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _snapper = new WindowSnapper(this, "Notepad");
        _snapper.Attach();
    }
}
```